# React, Typescript and Jest - Why is simple test failing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to use React with Typescript and test it with Jest.

I have a super simple component with an empty array in the state.

I'm trying to test that the array exist and that its empty.

I'm thinking it must be something with the way I have the `App.tsx` file set up.

`App.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

interface IState {
  gifts: string[];
}

interface IProps {}

class App extends Component<{}, IState> {
  state = {
    gifts: []
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Gift Giver</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import "./setUpTests";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import App from "./App";

const app = shallow(<App />);

it("renders correctly", () => {
  expect(app).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it("initializes the `state` with an empty list of gifts", () => {
  expect(app.state.gifts).toEqual([]);
});
```

test output

```
✓ renders correctly (6ms)
  ✕ initializes the `state` with an empty list of gifts (4ms)

  ● initializes the `state` with an empty list of gifts

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: []
    Received: undefined

      11 | 
      12 | it("initializes the `state` with an empty list of gifts", () => {
    > 13 |   expect(app.state.gifts).toEqual([]);
         |                           ^
      14 | });
      15 | 

      at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/App.test.tsx:13:27)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to create the `state` object in the `constructor`.

Just like the following:

```
constructor(props:any) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    gifts: []
  };
}
```

Read further here: [Adding Local State to a Class](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class)

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a typo, I just spotted

`expect(app.state().gifts).toEqual([]);`